# VSCode "variant is not a template", how to make vscode detect it?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am writing a simple structure in using vscode in c++

```cpp
#include <variant>
using namespace std;
struct Entry {
  string name;
  variant<double,int> v;
};
```

I am using the [C/C++ extension by Microsoft](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools).

Despite the fact that it's compiling just fine, somehow the extension is unable to detect the `variant` class.

How do I fix this issue with VScode?

Comment: Which C++ version have you set in the configuration?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it!

- Go to Extensions > C/C++ > Gear Icon > Extension Settings
- In upper search bar add "standard"
- Look for the "C_Cpp > Default: Cpp Standard" entry.
- Click on drop-down list and select the highest c++ standard that you need.
- Reload and the error goes away.

The Same goes for this kind of problems in C.
It seems like the default c++ standard of this extension can sometimes be insufficient.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the [clangd](https://open-vsx.org/extension/llvm-vs-code-extensions/vscode-clangd) extension (not the C++ one by Microsoft), add this in your `.vscode/settings.json` file:

```json
{
    "clangd.fallbackFlags": [
        "-std=c++17"
    ]
}
```

Then reload the extesion to apply the changes.

Answer (score 0):

For those who use `cl.exe` (VSCode guide on [configuring Microsoft C++](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc)) to compile and link C/C++ program:

- Look for `.vscode/task.json`.
- Add `"/std:c++latest"` to `args` list.
- Hit `Ctrl + Shift + B` to build.

More options regarding `cl.exe` can be found by typing `cl.exe /help` in `Developer Command Prompt for VS XXXX`.