# C/C++ vscode extension show error while there is none

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I have this program which compiles with the C++ 20 standard.

```
g++ -std=c++2a test.cpp
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    variant<int, string> v{"hello"};
    
    cout << get<string>(v) << endl;

}
```

I have the C/C++ extension installed, I changed the settings to take into account the C++ 20 standard [as proposed before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63703117/vscode-variant-is-not-a-template-how-to-make-vscode-detect-it)

`C_Cpp › Default: Cpp Standard > C++ 20`

I get the following error when hovering `variant`

```
identifier "variant" is undefined C/C++(20)
```

If I understood correctly, `variant` is part of `std` since C++ 17, so why is the extension unable to find it after telling it to use the C++ 20 standard ?

Edit 1:
The compiler version is
`g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0`

Edit 2:
I don't have a cpp_properties.json file, I just installed the extension and changed the C++ standard version in the settings.

Comment: which version of the compiler is it?

Comment: please show a [mre] with your `cpp_properties.json` file

Comment: `To enable C++20 support, add the command-line parameter -std=c++20 (use -std=c++2a in GCC 9 and earlier)` could be the VSCode extension does not recognize `c++2a`

Comment: Where should I add the command-line parameter ? I don't see this field in the settings of the vscode extension

Comment: In your `tasks.json` file where the other command line options are...

Comment: sry but I don't think I have a task.json file

Comment: without `cpp_properties.json` and correct filled in you get this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, the problem came from the `cpp_properties.json`.

Even after changing the settings, I found multiple hidden `.vscode` folders in the project with `cpp_properties.json` inside them with the wrong standard specified.

I manually changed the `cpp_properties.json` files and it was ok.